# Do I need to use jQuery.noConflict() when using SASS as well?

Tags: jquery

I am using both SASS and jQuery, and not sure if the two would have conflict over the dollar sign. Also, I am using them on js.fiddle, so cannot artificially prioritize any. Can someone tell me if the jquery noConflict function is needed in this case, or at all?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not required. Both are very different entities, you can use `$` in both.